# deleteItem PageBreakItem in google forms via apps script

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

I want to use deleteItem in apps script to delete an item from a form.
(I want to use this to clear the form and edit it).
Now, the code I wrote works fine for any item except the PageBreakItem.
I have tried it and as soon as there are PageBreakItems that I want to delete I get a "Failed to edit form" message. The code is here:

```
function generateOrderForm() {
  var orderForm = FormApp.openById('....myformID.....');
       // Clears all items after the 10th item.
  while(orderForm.getItems().length > 10){
      orderForm.deleteItem(10);
  }
}
```

Is this a known issue and if yes is there a solution?
Is there an other way to clear a form or a workaround for what I want?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this problem, page break items seem to delete just as well as other items.

Comment: Do you have any idea what might cause the "Failed to edit form" error when using this code? Maybe it has something to do with the fact that a multiple choice item navigates to these pages, I'll find out if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same question as you met. Your "PageBreakItem" is linked by other questions or other pages. Try to remove the link and run the script again.

Comment: Although that might be a good explanation of the reason, it's very hard to unlink the other items.